# The significance of space in this JS regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been learning some Javascript regular expressions today and I'm failing to understand how the following code works.

```
var toswop = 'last first\nlast first\nlast first';
var swapped = text.replace(/([\w]+)\b([\w ]+)/g,'$2 $1');
alert(swapped);
```

It correctly alerts the words swapped round in to the correct sequence however the following code (note the missing space after the second \w) doesn't work. It just print them in the original order.

```
var toswop = 'last first\nlast first\nlast first';
var swapped = text.replace(/([\w]+)\b([\w]+)/g,'$2 $1');
alert(swapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> #### `\w`
>
> Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
>
> For example, `/\w/` matches `'a'` in `"apple,"` `'5'` in `"$5.28,"`
>   and `'3'` in `"3D."`

When you add a space, you change the character set from alphanumerics and an underscore to alphanumerics and an underscore and a space.

Comment: You explain the significance of the space, But you don't answer his question? Why does the space make and break it?

Comment: @BuddhiP He explained the significance but didn't explain why it was significant?

Comment: @MattWhipple, yes, that is true. :) I've added an answer, please see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are incorrectly using `'\b'` to match with a space, but in JavaScript regular expressions `'\b'` matches with a beginning or end of word.

Therefore this `/([\w]+)\b/` part of the regular expression match only upto the end of word `'last'`. remaining string is `' first'` (note the space at the beginning).

Then to match with the remainder you need this `([\w ]+)`, this translates into **'One or more occurances of anyword character or space character'**. which is exactly what we need to match with the remainder string `' first'`.

*You can note that even when the words are swapped, there is a space before the word `'first'`.*

To prove this further: imagine you changed your input to :

```
var toswop = 'last first another\nlast first another\nlast first another';
```

You can see your swapped text becomes

```
 first another last
 first another last
 first another last
```

That is because last segment of the regular expression `([\w ]+)` kept matching with both spaces and word characters and included the word 'another' into the match.

But if you remove the space from square brackets, then it won't match with the remainder `' first'`, because its not a **string of  'word character'** but a **'space' + string of 'word character'**.

That is why you space is significant here.

But if you change your regex like this:

```
swapped = toswop.replace(/([\w]+)\s([\w]+)/g,'$2 $1');
```

Then it works without the space because `\s` in the middle with match with the space in the middle of two words.

Hope this clarifies your question.

See here for JavaScript RegEx syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_begin.asp

See here for my fiddle if you want to experiment more: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/P5Jqm/

Comment: I don't suggest you use w3schools as a reference. It's not a wiki and the content's accuracy is often questionable. [The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a much better resource.

Comment: So I keep hearing last few days. I'll keep that in mind. But can you share evidence on this?

Answer (score 1):

It goes through the expression like this. It will look for all word characters until a non-word character is found. That catches the first word.

Then it looks for the next match which is a space or a word character. So without the space in the square brackets the space in the name isn't matched. That is why it's failing for the alternative without the space.

I think it's better to write this explicitly putting the space in rather than the \b.